# Where would one find information on the fuel properties (temp, max ISP) of non-conventional rocket fuels?

Tags: fuel, engine-design

Yesterday's [Starship landing](https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/1336848931783786497/pu/vid/1280x720/hgx7ug6ui58DvPVF.mp4?tag=10) saw at least one Raptor burning copper. Given that copper oxidizes with oxygen at the temperatures and pressures found in a Raptor combustion chamber, what properties does it impart on the combustion?

What would be the exhaust velocity of a hypothetical tri-propellant methane-copper-oxygen engine? Would that translate to specific impulse in the same fashion as conventional (OK, methane isn't yet conventional) rocket fuels do? I'm assuming a molecular weight higher that hydrogen so less Isp of course, but how would it compare to e.g. RP-1? Would gaseous copper (gaseous in the chamber after oxidizing, but no reason that the stored fuel could not be solid) have a higher or lower molecular weight than hydrocarbons such as RP-1?

Comment: Copper's kind of hard to pump.

Comment: @OrganicMarble: Not necessarily. Just as control rods are inserted into fission reactors, so could copper rods be inserted into a combustion chamber.